# how to create table column that is a list of items from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to make a database table for a small invoice app i am making, and I made a table called "Invoice" which stores all my invoices. It has a column called "items" which should be a list of items invoiced to the customer. i.e. "Camera, film, lens".

The items are located on another table called "Items" which has "item_name" and "Item_id".

How can I make the "items" column in "Invoice" store a list of Items?

Thanks

Comment: you have to create two tables for invoice . 1 `invoice` which stores your one invoice number for customer. 2 `incoive_details` which will have all items purchased by that perticular customer with your `item_id`. with `item_id` as your foreign key

Comment: what columns should I add in invoice_details? and how many?

Comment: so you can have your `customer_id`,`item_id`,`Invoice_ID` as forign key and `Invoice_details_id` as your PK for that table and link both tables with `Invoice_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

Do some research on Foreign Key and try to implement them on your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join your tables. You will do this using Your Primary Key of one table and a foreign key in another. Use the below formula.

```
'SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;'
```

You will then use the below formula to select your data into a new table.

```
'SELECT *
INTO newtable [IN externaldb]
FROM table1;'
```